# Automatically sending sms from Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, sms

As I understood, it is possible but such applications are not allowed in the official stores.

The app should get permissions in advance, from the user, and then, at random times, send an SMS to a random user from the phone contact-list, without further user interaction.
My questions are:

1) Is it possible at all?
2) If so, is it something that the official stores will approve?

Comment: apple appstore would never approve that and it's pretty evil, if you ask me. Why would you want to send SMS at random times other than do harm to the user of your app?

Comment: No evil there! the contacts are actually a group - pre-defined, that permits it in advance. they all are using the app ..
I can't elaborate much more about it..

Comment: well that's what you tell the user, but that might not be the reality of it. Anytime you can decide to change that functionality to be malicious and that's not very good from the user point of view. But as correctly stated in the answer bellow, it's possible to do on android. Still, I wouldn't recommend it and rather instead of using SMS I would advise using solutions based on internet connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will definitely NOT approve this kind of app!

I have tried this for over 2 years now, even contacted Apple - there is no approval for this!

There has been an App in iTunes at sometime (how that could have passed the review process - nobody knows) This has been removed as soon as Apple got to know about this.

Besides the approval issue, there is no OFFICIAL way to even accomplish this.

While there are/were some direct calls to private libraries, using these would immediately be identified (even automatically nowadays).

Just stick with Apple's rules if your App allows - give the user some background information, why they need to explicitly press "send" again - otherwise you might get some bad reviews, since this fact is certainly not known among all iPhone users.

In Android this is just a normal usage of `SmsManager.getDefault();`

Answer (score 2):

1) In Android this is possible. If I recall correctly, there is no API for sending sms in iOS, without going through the stock sms application.

2) It's sketchy... Apple would probably not approve this kind of application, if it's even possible to make in iOS. Its never a good idea doing things behind the users back.

Comment: thanks. but, it's not behind their back. 
The user must approve it in advance.